# Anonymous login is not triggering onAuthStateChanged callback

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm logging in my users anonymously if they are not logged in, but the onAuthStateChanged callback is not being triggered. Additionally, whenever I try to use `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()`, it gives me a NullPointerException. Here is my code:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {

                    // do something

                } else {

                    mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            System.out.println("SIGNED IN ANONYMOUSLY");
                            System.out.println(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()); // crashes here
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        };
```

Been stuck on this for hours and I have no idea what the issue could be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty much sure its because your `signInAnonymously` call is not returning successful in `onComplete` callback.

Replace

```
System.out.println("SIGNED IN ANONYMOUSLY");
System.out.println(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

with

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    System.out.println("SIGNED IN ANONYMOUSLY");
    System.out.println(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
}
else{
    Log.i(TAG, "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
}
```

and check the exception

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, you're right. I'm getting this exception: http://pastebin.com/raw/AdyNrzR3 , do you have any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: Figured it out, didn't have anonymous login enabled in my authentication settings lol. Thanks for the help.